# Why rvalue references behave differently based on types?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I'm reading about C++ rvalue references and value categories for expressions. However, I'm not able to grasp (from a lvalue, xvalue, prvalue point of view) why the following code works as expected:

```
struct S {
    int a;
};

S&& t(S& a) {
    return (S&&)a;
}

int main()
{   
    S s = { 1 };
    t(s) = S{ 2 };
    cout << s.a; // prints 2
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas the following one doesn't even compile, and shows `error: using rvalue as lvalue`:

```
int&& t(int& a) {
    return (int&&)(a);
}

int main()
{   
    int s = 1;
    t(s) = 2; // error
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

To me, in both cases `t(s)` should behave as an `xvalue`. Hence, it can appear to the left of the assignment operator (not discussing operator overriding in this context). The standard literally says that *The result of calling a function whose return type is an rvalue reference is an xvalue.* Why is it behaving differently for `int` and for `struct S`? Is this behavior, in any way, predicted by the standard (or by cppreference.com)? I couldn't realize what order of ideas gets into this scenario.

I was expecting the second code to print `2`, based on the reasoning that the memory location of `s`, initially holding `1` would be overwritten by `2` by means of the `rvalue reference`.

Comment: AFAIR this is because assignment operators for class types are member functions, and it is allowed to call any member function on a rvalue. Perhaps you are calling it for its side effect (the compiler doesn't care that this particular assignment operator is fully compiler-generated and cannot have side effects, it's enough that it is possible in principle). Whereas for built-in types the assignment is always built-in too and it never makes sense to call it when lhs is a rvalue.

Comment: BTW this was the case even in C++98 before the introduction of rvalue references (check with e.g. `struct A{}; A foo() { return A(); }` --- you can do `foo() = A();` even in C++98 because it means `foo().operator=(A());`. C++11 could have disallowed it for the assignment operator, based on reference-qualified member function overloads,  but that would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by [the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#2):

> [Note 1: ...For example, **the built-in assignment operators expect that the left operand is an lvalue** and that the right operand is a prvalue and yield an lvalue as the result. **User-defined operators are functions**, and the categories of values they expect and yield are determined by their parameter and return types. — end note]

That is, the `operator=` used by `S` is actually a function that's implicitly generated by the compiler. So, the default one is like:

```cpp
S& operator=(const S&) { /*...*/ return *this; }
S& operator=(S&&){ /*...*/ return *this; }
```

This will allow the user to call the function, which behaves differently from the built-in operators; however, if you explicitly disable it by reference qualifiers:

```cpp
S& operator=(const S&) & { /*...*/ return *this; }
S& operator=(S&&) & { /*...*/ return *this; }
// Or e.g. S& operator=(S&&) & =default;
```

Then the function can only be used for lvalue.